# Automatically build kernel modules after unattended upgrades in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iscsi, upgrade, unattended, kernel-modules

For automatic upgrades I has installed `unattended-upgrades` package and configured it.

After each unattend kernel upgrade I must run following commands to recompile iscsi kernel modules:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
apt-get install --reinstall iscsitarget-dkms
service iscsitarget start
```

How to to force system do this automatically?

Comment: Is this a very old version of Ubuntu? All recent versions automatically build any registered dkms modules when new kernels are installed. I should point out that iscsitarget (IET) is pretty much deprecated these days and you may have problems building that on new kernels. You really want to be using LIO (eg. targetcli-fb).

Comment: I use 12.04 with latest upgrades and kernel from linux-image-lts-trusty. I don't know anything about targetcli-fb I didn't know that IET is pretty much deprecated. I use iscsitarget for clone virtual system to baremetal machines over the network with livecd and gparted. May be you can advise something else to use case ?